# Calculate total sum of squares between clusters in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

My objective is to compare which of the two clustering methods I've used `cluster_method_1` and `cluster_method_2` has the largest between cluster sum of squares in order to identify which one achieves better separation.

I'm basically looking for an efficient way to calculate the distance between each point of cluster 1 and all points of cluster 2,3,4, and so on.

example dataframe:

```
structure(list(x1 = c(0.01762376, -1.147739752, 1.073605848, 
2.000420899, 0.01762376, 0.944438811, 2.000420899, 0.01762376, 
-1.147739752, -1.147739752), x2 = c(0.536193126, 0.885609849, 
-0.944699546, -2.242627057, -1.809984553, 1.834120637, 0.885609849, 
0.96883563, 0.186776403, -0.678508604), x3 = c(0.64707104, -0.603759684, 
-0.603759684, -0.603759684, -0.603759684, 0.64707104, -0.603759684, 
-0.603759684, -0.603759684, 1.617857394), x4 = c(-0.72712328, 
0.72730861, 0.72730861, -0.72712328, -0.72712328, 0.72730861, 
0.72730861, -0.72712328, -0.72712328, -0.72712328), cluster_method_1 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "4", 
"6"), class = "factor"), cluster_method_2 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))



        x1     x2     x3     x4 cluster_method_1 cluster_method_2
     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>            <fct>           
 1  0.0176  0.536  0.647 -0.727 1                5               
 2 -1.15    0.886 -0.604  0.727 4                3               
 3  1.07   -0.945 -0.604  0.727 4                1               
 4  2.00   -2.24  -0.604 -0.727 4                3               
 5  0.0176 -1.81  -0.604 -0.727 2                4               
 6  0.944   1.83   0.647  0.727 2                2               
 7  2.00    0.886 -0.604  0.727 4                1               
 8  0.0176  0.969 -0.604 -0.727 2                1               
 9 -1.15    0.187 -0.604 -0.727 1                1               
10 -1.15   -0.679  1.62  -0.727 6                6
```

Comment: So you want to calculate all pairwise distances between the clusters?

Comment: Correct, efficiently!

Comment: I think you're looking for the Calinski-Harabasz Index / Variance Ratio Criterion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The within sum-of-squares for cluster *S<sub>i</sub>* can be written as the sum of all pairwise (Euclidean) distances squared, divided by twice the number of points in that cluster (see e.g. [the Wikipedia article on *k*-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Description))

[image]

For convenience we define a function `calc_SS` that returns the within sum-of-squares for a (numeric) `data.frame`

```
calc_SS <- function(df) sum(as.matrix(dist(df)^2)) / (2 * nrow(df))
```

It's then straightforward to calculate the within (cluster) sum-of-squares for every cluster for every method

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(method, cluster, cluster_method_1, cluster_method_2) %>%
    group_by(method, cluster) %>%
    nest() %>%
    transmute(
        method,
        cluster,
        within_SS = map_dbl(data, ~calc_SS(.x))) %>%
    spread(method, within_SS)
## A tibble: 6 x 3
#  cluster cluster_method_1 cluster_method_2
#  <chr>              <dbl>            <dbl>
#1 1                   1.52             9.99
#2 2                  10.3              0
#3 3                  NA               10.9
#4 4                  15.2              0
#5 5                  NA                0
#6 6                   0                0
```

The *total* within sum-of-squares is then just the sum of the within sum-of-squares for every cluster

```
df %>%
    gather(method, cluster, cluster_method_1, cluster_method_2) %>%
    group_by(method, cluster) %>%
    nest() %>%
    transmute(
        method,
        cluster,
        within_SS = map_dbl(data, ~calc_SS(.x))) %>%
    group_by(method) %>%
    summarise(total_within_SS = sum(within_SS)) %>%
    spread(method, total_within_SS)
## A tibble: 1 x 2
#  cluster_method_1 cluster_method_2
#             <dbl>            <dbl>
#1             27.0             20.9
```

---

By the way, we can confirm that `calc_SS` does indeed return the within sum-of-squares using the `iris` dataset:

```
set.seed(2018)
df2 <- iris[, 1:4]
kmeans <- kmeans(as.matrix(df2), 3)
df2$cluster <- kmeans$cluster

df2 %>%
    group_by(cluster) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(within_SS = map_dbl(data, ~calc_SS(.x))) %>%
    arrange(cluster)
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  cluster data              within_SS
#    <int> <list>                <dbl>
#1       1 <tibble [38 × 4]>      23.9
#2       2 <tibble [62 × 4]>      39.8
#3       3 <tibble [50 × 4]>      15.2

kmeans$within
#[1] 23.87947 39.82097 15.15100
```

Comment: That's good, thanks. However, I'm not looking for the withinSS. I'm looking for the SS of all points between clusters i and j for every i != j..

So basically SS for different clusters because I need a measurement of separation.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood (or there is a misunderstanding of what the within SS is): **I *do* calculate the within SS for the different clusters**. Those are values in the two columns for `cluster_method_1` and `cluster_method_2`. I also give the total within SS, which is just the sum of the individual within SSs. Are you perhaps confusing the within SS with the between SS?

Comment: Upon carefully re-reading your post, I noticed that you want to *"calculate the distance between each point of cluster 1 and all points of cluster 2,3,4"*. That seems to me an odd metric to use for comparing the "performance" of two clustering methods. It's odd because it's neither the within nor the between SS. Compare e.g. with k-means clustering where you minimise the within SS. Can you elaborate on what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Sure! Basically, I've applied two different clustering methods on the same dataset (Hierarchical K-means and SOMs). Now, we know that clustering in general has 2 objectives: i) The subjects that are in the same cluster need to be as similar as possible and ii) The subjects that are in different clusters need to be as dissimilar as possible. For the specific project I'm working on, (ii) is more important than (i). Thus, I want to measure how far my clusters are from each other but not just centroid distance; I want to measure distances of subjects that "live" in different clusters

Comment: I'm not familiar with *hierarchical* k-means clustering, but in standard k-means clustering the objective function is precisely the within SS. It's easy to show that minimising the within SS corresponds to maximising the between SS of the centroids. Within that context, I am not sure what you mean by *"ii) The subjects that are in different clusters need to be as dissimilar as possible"*. Dissimilar in what regard and in comparison to what? [...]

Comment: [continued] Coming back to your original goal to "*calculate the distance between each point of cluster 1 and all points of cluster 2,3,4"*": What would be your expected output? A distance for every point in every cluster? So for point 1 of cluster 1 you have the SS to all other points, for point 2 of cluster 1 you have the SS to all other points, and so on? How would that be useful?

Answer (score 2):

The total sum of squares, sum_x sum_y ||x-y||² is constant.

The total sum of squares can be computed trivially from variance.

If you now *subtract* the within-cluster sum of squares where x and y belong to the same cluster, then the between cluster sum of squares remains.

If you do this approach, it takes O(n) time instead of O(n²).

Corollary: the solution with the smallest WCSS has the largest BCSS.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the package clValid. It calculates a large number of indexes for validating clustering. The Dunn index is particularly appropriate for what you are trying to do. The documentation says that the Dunn index is the ratio between the smallest distance between observation not in the same cluster to the largest intra-cluster distance. The documentation for it can be found at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clValid/clValid.pdf.